# How to escape % in windows10 batch command in jenkins build step?

Tags: windows, jenkins

I defined below command in jenkins windows batch command build step:

```
for /r %%f in (.\*.exe) do echo %%f
```

But the `echo` doesn't print the file name. Instead it just prints `%f` to the console.

I have tried with single `%` as below but it doesn't help. It prints `f` to the console.

```
for /r %f in (.\*.exe) do echo %f
```

How can I escape `%` character on jenkins build step? I am not sure whether it relates to jenkins only.

Comment: I already tried single `%` but it doesn't help. It will print `f` instead of the file name.

Comment: That information should have been in your post from the start. Thanks for editing.

Comment: I would call the batch file directly rather than using a dos statement in the build step. You will have more control over variable expansion that way.

Comment: do you mean to write a batch and run that file from jenkins build step?

Comment: Jenkins can't handle `%` for windows via Jenkins String Parameters. You would have to define the variable in a build step for `Execute Windows Batch command`. Otherwise Jenkins will turn `%` into `%%` for you.

Comment: Windows cmd and batch treats `%` differently so you have to escape with different ways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Jenkins 2.60.2 on Windows 10, with two Firefox installer executables in my directory, running `for /r %%f in (.\*.exe) do echo %%f` in a Windows Batch command, I get the following output:

```
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Test
[Test] $ cmd /c call C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\jenkins4832870824680456992.bat
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Test>for /R %f in (.\*.exe) do echo %f 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Test>echo C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Test\.\Firefox Installer.en-US.exe 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Test\.\Firefox Installer.en-US.exe

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Test>echo C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Test\.\Firefox Installer.exe 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Test\.\Firefox Installer.exe
```

As you can see, it correctly treated the double `%%` as a single `%` when running the batch command, which makes sense, as it just calls `cmd /c call` on the temporary batch file that it creates, and that is the correct way of doing `%` syntax in a batch file.

I don't think it likely that this behavior would have changed much from different versions of Jenkins, but what version are you running?  Can you post the full output of your batch command?  Maybe there's something in there that can give us a clue.

Comment: what I got is that the `%%f` was translated to `%f` but the script doesn't treat it as a variable. instead, it treats it as a string. I know that running it through `cmd /c ` on windows works fine. The problem exists in jenkins windows batch step.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. If you can post your exact output, and your version information, maybe there's something there that will indicate the real issue.